# SQL Pivot swapping values in SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have two queries **Sales & Forecast** which I am bringing together in a UNION
These two queries at this point show correctly.
I then pivot the query to show each SKU and then a Column of **Sales** and then a column of **Forecast** but it appears that the values appear under the wrong column.

Below is my code - is there a obvious reason why it doesn't output as expected?

```
SELECT q.FY#, q.[Country Code], q.Family, q.Colour, q.Pack_Size, Forecast, Actuals, Forecast/nullif(Actuals,0)  as Change
FROM (

SELECT FY#, [Country Code], Family, Colour, Pack_Size, Forecast, Actuals
FROM (

    SELECT f.FY#, f.Attribute, f.[Country Code], f.Family, f.Colour, f.Pack_Size, sum(f.Packs) as Packs
    FROM [V3.1_JDAForecast](@Country, @FY) f
    group by f.FY#, f.Attribute, f.[Country Code], f.Family, f.Colour, f.Pack_Size

    UNION

    SELECT a.FY#, a.Attribute, a.[Country Code], a.Family, a.Colour, a.Pack_Size, sum(a.Packs) as Packs
    FROM [V3.1_JDAActuals](@Country, @FY) as a
    group by a.FY#, a.Attribute, a.[Country Code], a.Family, a.Colour, a.Pack_Size

) src
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Packs)
    for Attribute in ([Actuals], [Forecast])
) piv
) q
```

Comment: UNION removes duplicates which requires extra processing.  If that is not your intent then you should use UNION ALL.

Comment: Thanks Zorlolot - its a good tip for the future. In this case the two select queries are Table-valued Functions and any duplicates have already been taken care of in that. So in this instance I would save processing, possibly run time and I thank you for your input.